# Turning off mouse pointer when making an api call in angluar

Tags: angular

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but what I am doing right now is that when some of my child components are making API calls, we don't want people to be able to spam click the calls multiple times so what I did was made a sharedservice that my topmost parent component has in it's init that gets a "loading" boolean from the child components whenever they call an API that turns mouse actions off. But when I do this, my parent component throws an error in console.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'pointer-events: auto'. Current value: 'pointer-events: none'
```

```
public loading: boolean: true;

ngOnInit() {
  this._sharedData.loading.subscribe(value => {
    this.loading = value;
  })
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Or any way to prevent this error?

Comment: on loading true set a class instead on the body, .pointerNone{pointer-event: none}

Comment: You can also set button disable based on the loading condition

Comment: Hmm yea that's what I was doing. So when I do that and set a conditional class in my HTML on the topmost layer to change pointer-event depending on my loading boolean, it gives me that console error. It doesn't seem like a big deal(? maybe it is) but it's annoying having that error thrown everytime I make an API call lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class on the main container. whenever the service is being called.

```
public loading: boolean: true;

ngOnInit() {
  this._sharedData.loading.subscribe(value => {
    this.loading = value;
  })
}
```

In HTML

```
<div [ngClass]="{'pointerNone': loading}"></div>
```

CSS

```
.pointerNone{
  pointer-events: none
}
```

Comment: Hmm yea thats what I'm doing. and its giving me that console error